# powershell command Join-Path

Tags: powershell

1. Join-Path 'abc' 'deg' '*'   ---doesnt work
2. Join-Path 'abc' 'deg' | Join-Path -ChildPath '*'   ---works
3. Output required abc\deg\*

What to know whats the issue here for 1. ?

Answer (score 3):

In **PowerShell before version 7**, `Join-Path` takes only 2 args, where 1st (`-Path`) can be array of strings that are left part of path, and 2nd (`-ChildPath`) is single string that is right part of path.

You can do this, but I think this is not what you expect to get

```
> Join-Path @('abc', 'deg') '*'
# abc\*
# deg\*
```

To achieve what you want, you can use native method [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which has overloads for 3, 4 and array of path parts. But I'd recommend avoid using it if you plan running on Windows 7 for more than 2 parts because those overloads were introduced in **.net 4.0**, and on **.net 3.5** or lower this will fail.

```
# Variant1
$result = [System.IO.Path]::Combine('abc', 'deg', '*')

# Variant2
$parts = @('abc', 'deg', '*')
$result = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([string[]]$parts)

# Variant3 supported in .net before 4.0
$result = [System.IO.Path]::Combine('abc', [System.IO.Path]::Combine('deg', '*'))
# [System] is omitted, because it is loaded already
$result = [IO.Path]::Combine('abc', [IO.Path]::Combine('deg', '*'))

# Variant 4 ..meh...
$result = [String]::Join([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar, @('abc', 'deg', '*'))
$result = @('abc', 'deg', '*') -join [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
```

In **PowerShell version 7 and up**, `Join-Path` has additional third argument `-AdditionalChildPath` and can take any number of args.

```
# Short version based on positional args
> Join-Path 'abc' 'deg' '*' 'sub'
# abc\deg\*\sub

# Long version based on named args
Join-Path -Path 'abc' -ChildPath 'deg' -AdditionalChildPath @('*', 'sub')
# abc\deg\*\sub
```

Answer (score 0):

join-path only takes 2 arguments, unless you're in powershell 7.